# CMake install subdir headers in include dir

Tags: cmake

I am creating a new library. Header files are present in nested directories. Is it possible to install all headers directly under someprefix/include dir? I see .h files getting installed under /someprefix/include/subdir/something.h. I dont want subdir under include.

> Blockquote

```
   code structure:
   foo:
       CMakeList.txt
       src:
           CMakeList.txt
           sample.cpp
           sample.h
           bar: 
               barexample.cpp
               barexample.h
```

cmake install output:

> Blockquote

```
  <someprefix>/include/sample.h
  <someprefix>/include/bar/barexample.h
```

Expect  barexample.h to be under include not under include/bar/

Tried target_include_directories, target_sources etc. No success. Any help appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] and share the `CMakeLists.txt` to reproduce your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it.

I set header files in variable using

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE PHEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
```

and then used

```
install(FILES ${PHEADER } DESTINATION include)
```

Not sure this is the correct way, but it works. Earlier, I was using a custom installer which was causing the issue.